# How to undelete an answer deleted by a moderator

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I have asked a perfect question and got the solution. I posted it on the blog which is published on my company's website. I gave the link and explained the main components of the solution. It was even up voted by one user. Then also it was deleted by a moderator and I cannot undelete it. If I try, I get an error message: "A moderator has deleted this post and can not be undeleted."

How do I deal with this situation? Here is the link to my question: [How to upload data using chunked encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998450/how-to-upload-data-using-chunked-encoding)

And my deleted answer was:

> I found the way and uploaded it to my company's website.
>
> Please refer it from [here](http://blog.infostretch.com/2012/10).
>
> Search for "iOS: Unrevealed Better way of Communication" in the page and have the solution.

I have edited the answer so it now reads:

> Please refer it from [here](http://blog.infostretch.com/2012/10).
>
> Search for "iOS: Unrevealed Better way of Communication" in the page and have the solution.
>
> Here you need to create the bounded pair of streams. Use input stream to receive the data from audio unit and out stream to pass the data on chunk. Now use these stream in connection object for communication with server. This will allow you to listen the data and upload the data at same time.

Comment: I can't talk for the moderator but I suspect it is being flagged as spam.

Comment: Even I do not want to talk about it but my question is what should I do to undelete it?

Comment: Make sure it doesn't qualify as spam?

Comment: Very good question - you are a victim of the tyranny of the majority :)

Comment: There is no tyranny of the majority here. The answer was deleted by a moderator, presumably in response to a flag. If you've posted *many* answers with links to your blog, that is generally considered spammy behavior. Do exercise caution. (What is even more absurd is that your link doesn't even link to the relevant post!)

Comment: I have posted only a single answer with link. The link is also perfectly fine. I have mentioned in the answer that open the link and search for "iOS: Unrevealed Better way of Communication" in the page and have the solution. What is wrong with it? Before deleting it, they need to verify the validity.

Comment: @CodyGray You commented it because you cant see the deleted answer. Let me post the deleted answer in Question section it self.

Comment: It was deleted on Aug 4 '13 at 22:19. That's 10 months ago. I have to wonder why it's taken you so long to bring it up.

Comment: The images in the blog containing the code are dead (404). **The** reason link-only answers are considered bad answers.

Comment: Yes, I can see the deleted answer. The link is just a generic link to your blog. It doesn't link to any relevant post.

Comment: Short answer - don't post anything that's contingent on a link remaining valid.  Either post the content in the actual answer, or don't answer the question.

Comment: not a frequenter of meta, but seems like something strange is going on with this question.  it's very downvoted for a reasonable sounding question. also, the question that it is supposedly duplicating is newer than this one.

Answer (score 44):

To answer your question - the correct behaviour is to flag the answer with the "other" option explaining that you think you've improved the answer and ask for moderator review. We'll look at it and decide whether it can be undeleted.

However, you were being disingenuous by quoting your modified answer rather than the original answer that was flagged and deleted.

The original answer was little more than a link. You did admit that it was your website, but didn't include the relevant parts of the answer in the answer.

The modified version of the answer is better but still not brilliant and I wouldn't undelete it.