# How can I find out why an answer was deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

A 4-year old answer of mine ([Create a Custom Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355620/create-a-custom-tab/44358690#44358690)) was deleted yesterday. I can see the name of the moderator who deleted it and based on [How to undelete an answer deleted by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260989/how-to-undelete-an-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator) I need to resolve "issues" with the answer and then raise a custom flag to request un-deletion.

I believe that the answer was and still is valid. What was the reason of deletion so I can resolve it and get the answer restored?

Screenshot for <10k users:

> [image]

Comment: It's a link-only answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: It's not a link-only answer. It gives a troubleshooting step: compare your manifest with this one. It also suggests two other possible causes to the problem. Just because it has links doesn't mean it is link-only.

Comment: @RickKirkham Imagine the link goes dead. What are they to compare against? For the answer to be not link-only, the necessary information must be in the answer itself.

Comment: "to this one" -- you mean the one in a link? It doesn't include enough information to qualify as a bare-minimum answer. What's left is arguably a comment

Comment: Related / likely duplicate: [How to undelete an answer deleted by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260989/how-to-undelete-an-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator)

Comment: You seem to make habit of posting just the link as an answer.  eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/70660907/325727 It's not an answer unless you include the details from the linked page.

Comment: But beware of https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing -- it's easy to fall into the plagiarism trap when fixing link-only NAAs

Comment: See, I really dislike meta posts like this. The title question is a *damned good question*. But then you start to make it about a specific answer you want to have restored :/ That's something else entirely. Make up your mind already. Do you want to ask a damned good question, or do you want to make a complaint? Don't do both at once, now a damned good question is downvoted.

Comment: It reads like a forum post. [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). [Don't ask rhetorical questions in answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366692/how-do-you-know-stack-overflow-feels-unwelcoming#comment784795_399763) (10K+ only) - instead use affirmative statements. Or are they actually follow-up questions? Those belong in comments to the question.

Comment: @RickKirkham - That absolutely is a link only answer. It contains links, 2 questions that can never appropriately replied to by the author, and no information that actually answers the author’s question. I am honestly shocked that after nearly 5+ years that answer received zero votes.

Answer (score 18):

Meta is the right venue for challenging or inquiring the reason for moderator actions.

In this case, the answer was deleted due to a "Not an Answer"-flag, which was valid because the answer becomes invalid if the links die.

You may edit the answer to make it self-contained and then flag it for undeletion if you wish.