# Can I see if my comment was deleted for violating rules?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I commented on this question [My nested for loop breaks 3 loops back instead of one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70699979/14277722).

I pointed out the ambiguities of the question and my reason to vote to close because of syntax errors in the provided example code. My comment was (paraphrased):

> How do you know the result of the `break` statement in your example code? There are some errors before reaching the `break` statements. `dic.values()` won't iterate over *key,value* pairs, you don't use any of your variables, you have two `else` branches, an `except` clause needs at least one statement. Please provide a [mre].

I'm particularly interested in whether my comment violates any rules.

Comment: It probably didn't break *rules*, but it isn't like comments have a guarantee of persisting, like, period.

Comment: No, the best you can do is ask here with the small chance that maybe the mod who took action might see the question before it is burried/closed.  If the reason was problematic enough to put you at risk of any kind of account action, you would have received a mod message.. so you're probably fine.

Comment: ... but there is no harm in your asking on meta in a kind non-accusatory way, *as you are doing*. Much appreciated.

Comment: It was almost certainly removed as No Longer Needed since the question now has a close notice that also asks for an MRE.

Comment: @BSMP - That would have been my reasoning as well, the way it looks now. But the comment was deleted before the question was closed (the referenced question was closed shortly after I posted this question).

Comment: It seems to me that some comments get unnecessary removed,  perhaps due to the current hypersensitive awareness of "welcoming"'ness.  Whether it's due to automatic deletion based on flags, or mod action I can't say.  In any case, I feel that many objective but critical comments have a high chance of deletion

Comment: Was there at least one close vote at the time you noticed it was gone? I think the OP can see the close reason as soon as they have one vote for it. We'd need a mod to say for sure but if there weren't any close votes either my only other guess is it got swept up with other comments that needed removing.

Comment: This looks like a perfectly cromulent comment to me. I've posted many similar ones and would have posted a similar one on this specific question, *even after it was closed* – knowing why the comment was removed would be helpful indeed.

Comment: And it happens [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415273/424903)! "Can I somewhere see the reason why my comment was deleted?" is a perfectly reasonable question (the answer is no). And then you flip the meta post to be about a specific comment which is something different entirely. Why is this a trend?

Comment: @Gimby - that's true (even if your referenced question is about a deleted answer). I noticed this myself after reading EJoshuaS' answer and didn't want to devalue it by changing the title. My actual question is in the title, the body is an example provided. A better title would have been: 'Can I see if my comment was deleted for violating rules?'.

Comment: Basically, no, you can't. There are many threads discussing this under different lights, but the simple fact is that comments are ephemeral and one shouldn't feel particularly attached to them. They can be flagged as "no longer needed" are routinely deleted. The better course of action is to [let it go](https://youtu.be/moSFlvxnbgk) and move on.

Comment: We don't often have comment discussions in SOCVR but if you wonder if a comment is up to par for moderating a post, feel free to ask in SOCVR. Or you might even like our stock comments: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/blob/master/sites/stackoverflow.com/questions.md which go well with the auto review comment user script: https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts

Comment: You can also check whether your comment triggered the [heat detector](https://higgs.sobotics.org/reports?pageNumber=1&dashboard=1&hasFeedback=any&conflicted=any), although this doesn't always mean that the comment was or was not problematic.

Comment: Minor: It is paraphrased, but *"How do you know..."*, when ***hastily read***, *may* come over accusing the user (I know it is not the case, but it may be perceived that way). Perhaps avoid "you" to focus more on the content and less on the user? Call to action at the end can still include "you".

Comment: @PeterMortensen - That's a good observation. I will try to take this into account in future comments.

Answer (score -3):

No. Comments aren't intended to be permanent; they're subject to being deleted at any time without explanation.

Comment: Yeah ambiguous because the meta post asks two questions. Is that "No you can't see why it was deleted" or "No the comment does not violate any rules" ?

Comment: I specified the title of the question after you answered and Gimby's comment. Now it might look like an incorrect answer, considering Kevin B's comment *If the reason was problematic enough to put you at risk of any kind of account action, you would have received a mod message*