# Email notification about a closed question with broken links and typo

Tags: bug

I received an email notification from *do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email* about the closing of this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415300/can-i-see-if-my-comment-was-deleted-for-violating-rules) about 12 hours after the question was closed. This seems to be [legit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338332/is-email-from-do-not-replystackoverflow-email-legit).

But both links to 'https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/ls/click?upn=' to *Review similar questions* and to my original question are broken and lead to an error message, which contains an error in the phrase 'If are copying ...'.

This is the error message after clicking on the link (I have redacted the token due to security concerns)

[image: Error message]

Now I'm wondering if this is not a legitimate notification or a bug?

Comment: That is their [email domain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338332/6083675), but the rest of this question stands as a bug report.

Comment: @Laurel - Thx. I added the source to my question.

Comment: Looks strange that there is nothing after that "upn=" ... maybe your email client cut that off?

Comment: @Tom - There are tokens after the `upn=`, I redacted that part before posting the image due to security concerns. If a mod confirms it's safe, I'm happy to add the full links.

Comment: That's fine. I missed that you wrote, that you redacted the token.